# Linq to find the length of the value of the column in the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and a column; the column might have many values, and each value's length may vary.

If the length exceeds 100, I want to append /n at the end of it.

Need your help.

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail, it is unanswerable in its current form as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please supply us with your code.

Comment: Jamiec Thanks for your comment.As I am a begginner I wasnt able to do it.Next time If I ask I will be more specific.But I dont know why you people reducing the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give it a try, though a lot of questions are open (what type of list, what a column, ...).

In short: you can use **[`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)** to insert text at a specified postition.

Assuming you have a `List<Foo>`, the class `Foo` has a `string` property `Value` (your column). If it's `Length` exceeds 100 the line should be wrapped:

```
foreach(Foo foo in foos)
{
    if(foo.Value.Length > 100)
        foo.Value = foo.Value.Insert(100, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx

Here's running code with sample data.

http://ideone.com/sUKLk